# How to make custom rounded UIImageView subclass?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, storyboard, uikit

I want to make my custom round `UIImageView` and show it in storyboard.

I've done next:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
        super.layer.cornerRadius = super.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2    
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        super.layer.cornerRadius = super.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        super.layer.cornerRadius = super.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
    }
}
```

And my imageView in storyboard is RoundedImageView class selected.
But in storyboard it's still showing as rectangle. How can I realize it?
When I'm running code its rounded.
Thanks

Comment: You are saying that when application runs, it rounded but on IB it shows rectangular.

Comment: @ankit yes, thats it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should set radius after `layouts` have been applied.

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it in the evening and mark it, if it helps:)

Comment: Thanks. Thats it. But some code review. Confirm it pls ;)

Comment: wc :) . Your code is fine, but just one tweak, there is no need for super to set corner radius.

Comment: what mistake are you talking about.

Comment: "there is no need for super to set corner radius" - What do you mean?

Comment: Is there a reason you included the initializer overrides other than the original had them?